# How to call a method from a casted object - Reflection API

Tags: java, reflection, bukkit

I need help using a method from a casted Type in Java. Without reflections it would look like `PlayerConnection con = ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection;`, but due to the fact that the API I'm using for this program/plugin, the package suffix changes by version number, so I'm trying to figure out Reflections to get it to work. And later in the code, I'm trying to use the `con` variable to send it as a packet, using a method inside the `PlayerConnection` type. So without reflections it would look like `con.sendPacket(packet);` The packet variable I think I got it.

For background code information, I have already created a method to get the version of the server, and created another method to get the class. So instead of showing `Class.forName();` can you type getClass(""), the `getClass()` method returns Class and already adds the package name inside. For more information this will be an example:

```
input:
getClass("Packet");

output:
net.minecraft.1_8R2.Packet;
```

It'll will return the class of that package.

Comment: I suppose you are realizing "Decorator" pattern. Follow by [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can get a new instance of a [`Class<?>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) by using [`.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance())

```
Class<?> clazz = getClass("Packet");
Object packet = clazz.newInstance();
```

Then, to get the `CraftPlayer` class, you could use:

```
Class<?> craftplayer = getClass("CraftPlayer"); 
//make another method that chooses the org.bukkit.* class
//instead of the net.minecraft.server.* class, and use that here
//in place of getClass()
```

Then, to get the handle of the player, you could use:

```
Method getHandle = craftplayer.getMethod("getHandle");
Object nms = getHandle.invoke(player);
```

Next, you could get the `sendPacket()` method by using:

```
Field connfield = nms.getClass().getField("playerConnection");
Object connection = connfield.get(nms);
Method sendPacket = connection.getClass().getMethod("sendPacket", clazz); 
//clazz is getClass("Packet");
```

and then you could invoke it with the packet using:

```
sendPacket.invoke(connection, packet);
//packet is getClass("Packet").newInstance()
```

So, you could use something like this:

```
try{
  Class<?> clazz = getClass("Packet");
  Object packet = clazz.newInstance();

  Class<?> craftplayer = getClass("CraftPlayer"); 
  //make another method that chooses the org.bukkit.* class instead of the net.minecraft.server.* class, and use that here

  Method getHandle = craftplayer.getMethod("getHandle");
  Object nms = getHandle.invoke(player);

  Field connfield = nms.getClass().getField("playerConnection");
  Object connection = connfield.get(nms);
  Method sendPacket = connection.getClass().getMethod("sendPacket", clazz); 
  sendPacket.invoke(connection, packet);
}
catch(Exception ex){
  //an error occurred, and the packet could not be sent.
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But the think is that `PlayerConnection` and `CraftPlayer` are both from the `net.minecraft.1_8R1;` package. So I need that 2nd to last line to be dynamic. Sorry If I wasn't being clear.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you just use `((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(packet)` I don't think you'll have to import anything...

Comment: `CraftPlayer` will have to be imported to cast it `player`

Comment: @DennisOfficial I just edited the answer, you'll just need to make another method like `getClass()`, except make it get `org.bukkit.*` classes instead of `net.minecraft.server.*` classes, and use that in place of `getClass()` for `getClass("CraftPlayer")`